# problems converting ISO date in mongo using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following data in my mongo document:

```
"last_assigned" : ISODate("2016-11-10T20:34:36.000Z")
```

When i query the database for documents that include dates like the above, after my attempt to convert it, this is what my var_dump shows:

```
object(DateTime)[22]
  public 'date' => string '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 1
  public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
```

And this is what my code looks like - "$value['last_assigned']" is what I get back from the db...

```
            if (!empty($value['last_assigned'])) {
                $tempdate = new MongoDate(strtoTime($value['last_assigned']));
                var_dump($tempdate->toDateTime());                  
            }
```

How can i write my code such that it will display the proper value for the date?

**EDIT 1**

I tried to change the code like this:

```
                $tempdate = (string)$value['last_assigned']->sec;
                $tempdate = new MongoDate(strtotime($tempdate));
                var_dump($tempdate->toDateTime());
```

This is what the vardump shows:

```
object(DateTime)[22]
  public 'date' => string '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 1
  public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
```

Comment: Try converting the last_assigned to string before pasing it through the strtoTime function.

Comment: Are you using the mongo php driver ? or you just querying the data directly ? If you are querying the data directly you may want to save the date as string "2016-11-10T20:34:36.000Z". So in essence the new MongoDate(strtoTime("2016-11-10T20:34:36.000Z") should look like this.

Comment: @Veeram i'm using the mongoclient driver for php.  I know it's deprecated... we will be upgrading everything soon.  But for now... that's what I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php, I had to do something like this:

```
$tempdate =date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $value['last_assigned']->sec);
$did_details['last_assigned'] = $tempdate;
```